# EJB context JNDI lookup failure within EntityListener's @PreUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I have a JPA EntityListener in which I'm doing the same JNDI lookup for *"java:comp/EJBContext"* in both `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` callback methods. While the lookup is successful during the `@PrePersist` callback method, it keeps failing during the `@PreUpdate` callback method.

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.19.Final and a Websphere AS 8.5.5.3 build cf031430.01 (Java EE 6 / EJB 3.1 / JPA 2.0).

The code is quite simple :

```
public class AuditedEntityListener {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditedEntityListener.class);

  private static final String STANDARD_EJB_CONTEXT_NAME = "java:comp/EJBContext";

  SessionContext lookupSessionContext() {
    try {
      return InitialContext.doLookup(STANDARD_EJB_CONTEXT_NAME);
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
      LOGGER.error("Lookup failure", ne);
      return null;
    }
  }

  @PrePersist
  void prePersist(IAuditedEntity entity) {
    lookupSessionContext();
  }

  @PreUpdate
  void preUpdate(IAuditedEntity entity) {
    lookupSessionContext();
  }

}
```

Here is the trace :

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "comp/EJBContext" not found
>   in context "java:".   at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1229)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1142)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:422)
>   ~[na:1.7.0]   at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.doLookup(InitialContext.java:295)
>   ~[na:1.7.0]   at
>   my.AuditedEntityListener.lookupSessionContext(AuditedEntityListener.java:29)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   my.AuditedEntityListener.getUserName(AuditedEntityListener.java:34)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   my.AuditedEntityListener.preUpdate(AuditedEntityListener.java:74)
>   [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.7.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
>   ~[na:1.7.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>   ~[na:1.7.0]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
>   ~[na:2.6 (04-09-2014)]    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.ListenerCallback.invoke(ListenerCallback.java:48)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler.callback(EntityCallbackHandler.java:110)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler.preUpdate(EntityCallbackHandler.java:95)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3FlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(EJB3FlushEntityEventListener.java:65)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:334)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:285)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:165)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:230)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:100)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:109)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]    at
>   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredSyncs.coreDistributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:291)
>   [com.ibm.tx.jta.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:153)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:2382)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:586)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1028)
>   [com.ibm.tx.jta.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:962)
>   [com.ibm.tx.jta.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)
>   [com.ibm.tx.jta.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:949)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:262)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:567)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4491)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]

Comment: This is a product limitation or bug.  You will need to open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Thank you Brett, we opened a PMR with IBM as per your advice and it was indeed a bug.

Comment: I remember working on a fix while at IBM, so I'm glad it could be resolved satisfactorily for you :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brett pointed out, it was a bug on IBM's side. The issue was fixed in version 8.5.5.9 of Websphere.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI52932